# Only enable console session RDP on Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

I need to limit 1 machine's RDP capabilities to only allow the console session(much as the windows client behaviour).
It is a windows server 2003 R2 std.

As far as I know I can limit the number of sessions(Active) in server 2003 rdp config. But no option to only allow console sessions.

Anyone got any britght ideas?
Id rather not install xp/vista/win7 on this server.
VNC is not an option.

Cheers

Comment: Are you saying you want to allow RDP access, but only with the console (/admin) switch?

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

poor solution:
make a login script. If the connection is not console, logoff:

> logoff 1

This will logoff session 1. If you are connecting in rdp through the console, you are session 0 and not 1

you can detect better using qwinsta and a script to check output of it.

Comment: Well, your "poor solution" is actually the first solution ive got this far:) 1 point for that. Im still looking for something more exiting if you guys got any brigt ideas.

Comment: 2 poor others way to consolidate through GPO:
Restrict Terminal Services users to a single remote session
Limit number of connections (set it to 1)

 (computer \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Terminal Services)

I am afraid you won't have better. If others admin respect the logon script that do the logoff, it should be ok.

Comment: To restrict TS to 1 session, only restricts to active sessions and does not care if its console or not. Your still able to logon to multiple sessions just not at the same time.

Comment: That's why i named them "poor". It just add more restriction, to get closer to your objective, without being the true answer.
The best way i found is the logon script that logoff when you are not in console

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to see how the remote computer draws the console wrapper, or do you need a console-only access?

If it's the latter, consider using SSH - both OpenSSH and DropBear should be able to run on WS 2003; you're only transmitting the characters, not a part of the screen, plus the connection is encrypted.

Comment: I need the GUI console session of the RDP for a crappy app that feeds our backoffice system, no other method is supported by the vendor:/. So just Shell access is of no use, thx anyways:)